# How to categorize value using apply function and lambda

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I'm trying to categorize an example table to 3 category using apply and lambda but the result is always mature, I dont get it so here is the code :

```py
name=["rian","nancy","intan","rubim"]
age=["30","20","20","12"]
gender=["male","female","female","male"]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name":name,
    "age":age,
    "gender":gender
})

def category (age):
    if age<20:
        return 'kids'
    elif umur==20:
        return 'youth'
    else:
        return 'mature'

df['category']=df['age'].apply(age)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. you have to call `apply` with the function name, `category`
2. the `category` function references an undefined variable `umur`. Should this be `age`?
3. Your `age` data is of type string, but you want to compare it numerically.

Fixing these problems gives:

```py
name = ["rian", "nancy", "intan", "rubim"]
age = [30, 20, 20, 12]
gender = ["male", "female", "female", "male"]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": name,
    "age": age,
    "gender": gender
})

def category(age):
    if age < 20:
        return 'kids'
    elif age == 20:
        return 'youth'
    else:
        return 'mature'

df['category'] = df['age'].apply(category)
```

with the resulting DataFrame:

```
    name  age  gender category
0   rian   30    male   mature
1  nancy   20  female    youth
2  intan   20  female    youth
3  rubim   12    male     kids
```

I also suggest you to follow Python formatting conventions to make your code more readable.

Comment: Thank you for the help... yes the 'umur' variable should be 'age' in this case... that is really helpfull

Comment: @mikhaelfebrian please also note that using `apply` is slow for larger data sets. Simple transformations like these `if` checks can be easily vectorized, making the code much faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
name = ["rian", "nancy", "intan", "rubim"]
age = ["30", "20", "20", "12"]
gender = ["male", "female", "female", "male"]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": name,
    "age": age,
    "gender": gender
})

df.age = df.age.astype(int)
df['category'] = df['age'].apply(lambda x: 'mature' if x > 20 else 'kids' if x < 20 else 'youth')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer... it is nice knowing that there are two types to categorize dataframe using lambda